# Does Google AppEngine Ruby flexible Environment support task queues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I used to use Task Queues provided by google when I was using php runtime. Now i'm switching to ruby.
So I read the whole documentation for the Ruby Runtime and Task Queues is not mentioned at all. should i use some third party queuing system like Requeue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, Task Queues are *not* currently supported with Ruby.  You can however have a look at Cloud Pub/Sub, which enables similar scenarios:

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/

The [gcloud ruby gem](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-ruby) has support for Pub/Sub, and we have a few samples as well:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docs-samples/tree/master/pubsub

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

In rails you have delayed_jobs and sidekiq.

Here is a nice compare between these 2 technologies.
https://www.sitepoint.com/comparing-background-processing-libraries-sidekiq/

imho sidekiq is much better.

Comment: thx! i'm aware of the third part gems but this doesn't answer my question regarding google appengine